# Does a UIWebView drive visits to a third party website?

Tags: ios

Do apps that have a UiWebView generate web traffic to other websites?

I'll explain. Is there a difference between launching a link on safari vs UIWebView from within the app? I'm looking at it from the receiving web page (page views, ad views etc...) Is the UIWebView a calid way to boost site traffic to a third party website while keeping the user in your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIWebView is basically a control that let you embed web content into a native iOS application, supports static or dynamic web content.

UIWebView is like Sfari without any controls (back, forward, bookmark etc) but you can provide this functions trough native code.

So yes, you can use it to "boost" the site traffic while keeping the user it the app, but only if the users stays on the web view and only if your app pass the apple check, just so you know an app that contains only web views will be rejected from app store.

Also I don't think this approach will be successful because many iOS users will not use the app if it provides mainly web content into a web view, the users like native apps with fancy UI.

But just as a conclusion, yes you can "boost" the site traffic from a web view but I won't recommend this approach.

Comment: Downvotes are most likely due to lack of clarity in the question. It's very hard to understand what's being asked.